# newtxmath/lmodern broken?

Tags: symbols, newtxmath, lmodern

I just updated my `MiKTeX` packages. Output now seems to be missing mathematical operators if I load both `newtxmath` and `lmodern`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

$(3 + 5) \times 2 = \lambdaup$

\end{document}
```

The output on my system is missing the brackets and + symbol. I am (relatively) certain that this behaviour is new - is one/both of the packages broken?

Comment: Quick counter-question: What are you trying to achieve by loading `lmodern` after `newtxmath`? If you want mix and (mis!)match Latin Modern numerals with Times Roman `\times`, `=`, and `\lambdaup` symbols, you needn't load `lmodern` at all.

Comment: in the log you will see Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
They are not so much broken as naturally incompatible. newtxmath changes all the commands to fit the encoding of the txmath fonts then you switched fonts to latin modern

Comment: @Mico What I want to achieve is adding `\lambdaup`. This symbol is provided by `newtxmath`, but this also makes font changes which I do not want - which is why I load `lmodern` afterwards.

Switching `newtxmath` to the older `txfonts` produces the output I want to achieve, but `txfonts` is presumably superseded by `newtxmath`.

Comment: changing the entire math font to times roman just to get an upright lambda seems  excessive though?

Comment: upgreek package perhaps? I addes this to my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the log you will see

```
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
```

They are not so much broken as naturally incompatible.

`newtxmath` changes all the commands to fit the encoding of the txmath fonts then you switched fonts to latin modern

If you really want Latin Modern Text paired with Times Roman style Math, then load the packages in the other order so that the math settings match the math fonts in use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\tracinglostchars2

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

$(3 + 5) \times 2 = \lambdaup$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However These fonts don't really match at all so normally you would just use `\usepackage{lmodern}` to have Latin Modern text and math, or `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` to have new tx (Times Roman style) text and math.

an upright lambda better fitting with latin modern is provided by `upgreek` which only adds these letters and doesn't change the entire math setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\tracinglostchars2

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

$(3 + 5) \times 2 = \uplambda$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, `upgreek` does the job perfectly. I wish I'd known about it (much) sooner!

Answer (score 1):

The Tex Gyre fonts and their corresponding Math fonts go well together by design.

`unicode-math` package provides (amongst other things, such as `math-style=` option) the `\up`... prefix for upright Greek symbols, e.g., `\uplambda`:

[image: upright lambda]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TexGyreTermes}
\setmathfont{TexGyreTermes-Math}
%(λ     )


\begin{document}
\noindent Text mode (with TeX Gyre Termes), and a formula (in TeX Gyre Termes-Math):
$(3 + 5) \times 2 = \uplambda$

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here is a version with a few more fonts:

[image: TeX Gyre Math fonts]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TexGyreTermes}
\setmathfont{TexGyreTermes-Math}
%(λ     )
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand { \swapfont } { O{#2} m } {
\def\ftextname{#1}
\setmainfont{TexGyre\ftextname}
\setmathfont{TexGyre#2-Math}
\par\bigskip\noindent Text mode (with TeX Gyre \ftextname), and a formula (in TeX Gyre #2-Math):
$(3 + 5) \times 2 = \uplambda$
}


\begin{document}
\noindent Text mode (with TeX Gyre Termes), and a formula (in TeX Gyre Termes-Math):
$(3 + 5) \times 2 = \uplambda$
\swapfont{Bonum}%5-7 seconds to re-initialise all maths symbols with new font
\swapfont[Adventor]{DejaVu}
\swapfont{Pagella}
\swapfont{Schola}
\end{document}
```